# How to set StaticFileServer() using Kitura?

Tags: swift, localhost, fileserver, kitura, server-side-swift

I want to see files in my localhost directory using Kitura.
I've written:

```
router.all("/test/*", middleware: StaticFileServer())
```

but it didn't seem to work

I want to all files in my directory. Similar to directoryIndex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can pass the path to a directory to serve to `StaticFileServer`, as `path` parameter, by default it is `"public"`:

`router.all("/test/", middleware: StaticFileServer(path: "MyDirectoryWithStaticFiles"))`

Then you will be able to access the files in this directory, but not the directory itself. E.g., you will be able to perform GET `/test/someFile.html`, but not `/test/`. You will be able to GET `/test/`, if your directory will contain `index.html`.

See https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura-Sample for example of using `StaticFileHandler`.

Comment: Thank you, but I meant something different. I've edited the question, maybe now it's more clear ;)
Exactly. I want to access the directory itself. As far I as understood it's not possible with Kitura, right?

Comment: Correct, you cannot get a list of files of a directory with Kitura.

Comment: thank you! Is there any reason, why this is not possible with Kitura? Security reasons?

Comment: I think it is possible, this directory browsing feature is just not implemented.